# How to use Mockito for Behaviors related to Databse Interaction

Tags: unit-testing, dao, mockito

I have been searching the net for a simple answer to the question for a few days now. I now want someone to guide me in the right direction. I am a Software Trainee currently working on Enterprise Java Beans.

Also, to establish how confused I am, my mind just doesn't accept mocking and even stubbing as a proper way of testing what you have or may develop.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?  It's not clear how to help you.  Stubbing and verifying help you isolate one part of your system, so that you can test it without the test results being influenced by the behaviour of other parts of your system.  Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Are you using the DAO pattern for your database interaction?

Comment: -1 for not having a question.  I got a little bio and that you are confused.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my mind just doesn't accept mocking and even stubbing as a proper way
>   of testing what you have or may develop

You will see as you gain more experience the value of mocking/stubbing.  Keep in mind that testing in isolation is the bailiwick of unit-tests.  Integration tests are another matter.

Unit testing things in isolation is a good way to establish a baseline of working functionality.

The only way to test in isolation is with mocks/stubs.  Otherwise a lot of your tests would end up having to hit the database (in a standard webapp), not to mention you would need to wire up a full stack of components for every test.

Consider a situation where you have to unit test a high level controller.  That controller uses a service, which uses 2 DAOs.  To test that the controller returned the correct data, you have to either

1)  Just mock the service, tell it to expect a call and return some data, and then assert that the correct data is returned.

or

2)  Create an instance of the service.  Create an instance of each DAO, configured any internal stuff it needs.  PUt the DAOs in the service.  Populate your database with data.

Which sounds like more work?  Keep in mind that the service itself is tested in isolation, as are the DAOs.

Also, testing with mocking/stubbing in mind promotes a cleaner design. It is generally established that loosely coupled, tightly integrated code is a good way to do things.  Thinking about how you are going to test things naturally lends itself to that design.

Comment: The poster asked "how to use Mockito for Behaviors related to Databse Interaction".  How is this an answer?

Comment: @david, my answer was more about "my mind just doesn't accept mocking and even stubbing as a proper way of testing what you have or may develop."

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. I never came back to this, but I got hang of it now.